# Is it possible to install a service pack to a SQL 2012 Express instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, express-edition

I have a SQL 2012 Express instance that is on Service Pack 3. I am trying to find a way to update it to Service Pack 4 but this doesn't seem to be possible or maybe I am just not finding the right answer? Anyone know if this is possible and if so, can you provide a little guidance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just now figured it out. right after posting the question... should have waited a few more min.

I was trying to install SQL 2012 SP4 but it wasn't letting me choose the express instance, to apply the update to, only our other standard edition instance. I realized I had downloaded the x64 SP4 package and that when the Express instance was installed it was installed with the x86 version. I downloaded the x86 SP4 package and now it is letting me update the instance.

Maybe this will help someone in the future.